# Shell : Variable in Loop

Tags: database, shell, loops

I need some help. I want to backup multiple databases but the path variable is not present in the output. This is my code.

```
DB_BACKUP_PATH='/home/test'
DATABASE_NAMES='db_test_1 db_test_2 db_test_3'

for db_name in "${DATABASE_NAMES[@]}"
do
    echo $DB_BACKUP_PATH/$db_name
done
```

The output is

```
/home/test/db_test_1 db_test_2 db_test_3
```

Instead, I want it to be

```
/home/test/db_test_1 /home/test/db_test_2 /home/test/db_test_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it in this way.

```
DB_BACKUP_PATH='/home/test'
declare -a arr=("db_test_1" "db_test_2" "db_test_3")
for db_name in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$DB_BACKUP_PATH/$db_name"
done
```

OR in case you want to create an array by a variable then try:

```
DB_BACKUP_PATH='/home/test'
DATABASE_NAMES='db_test_1 db_test_2 db_test_3'
IFS=' ' read -r -a arr <<< "$DATABASE_NAMES"
for db_name in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$DB_BACKUP_PATH/$db_name"
done
```

Output will be as follows.

```
/home/test/db_test_1
/home/test/db_test_2
/home/test/db_test_3
```